# create multiple folders using loops in python

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop, mkdir

I want to write a function in python that creates a folder everytime a given condition is true. I don't know how many times this condition will be fulfilled. It will be like

step_1 condition true create folder1 
step_2 condition true create folder2 
...
step_n condition true create foldern

Comment: You can use os.makedirs to create new folder (and os.path.exists to check whether folder exists) - if thats what youre asking for.

Comment: No, what I am asking for is how to increment the counter automatically everytime the condition is true without using a for loop because I don't know how many times the condition will be met.

Comment: while your condition is True, keep on looping

Comment: then you want `while evaluate_condition():`  And the question should be _'how do I loop while a condition is `True`_ not about creating folders.

Answer (score 4):

A loop with `os.mkdir` or `os.mkdirs`

https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html

> `os.mkdir(path[, mode])`
>
> Create a directory named path with numeric mode mode. The default mode is 0777 (octal). If the directory already exists, OSError is
>   raised.
>
> On some systems, mode is ignored. Where it is used, the current umask value is first masked out. If bits other than the last 9 (i.e.
>   the last 3 digits of the octal representation of the mode) are set,
>   their meaning is platform-dependent. On some platforms, they are
>   ignored and you should call chmod() explicitly to set them.
>
> It is also possible to create temporary directories; see the tempfile module’s tempfile.mkdtemp() function.
>
> Availability: Unix, Windows.
>
> `os.makedirs(path[, mode])`
>
> Recursive directory creation function. Like mkdir(), but makes all intermediate-level directories needed to contain the leaf directory.
>   Raises an error exception if the leaf directory already exists or
>   cannot be created. The default mode is 0777 (octal).
>
> The mode parameter is passed to mkdir(); see the mkdir() description for how it is interpreted.

so something like:

```
import os

for i in range(n):
    # makeadir() evaluates your condition
    if makeadir(i):
        path = 'folder {}'.format(i)
        if not os.path.exists(path):
            os.mkdir(path)
```

edit: if you have a single condition:

```
import os

i = 1
while eval_condition():
    path = 'folder {}'.format(i)
    if not os.path.exists(path):
        os.mkdir(path)
    i += 1
```

Comment: the problem is that I don't know n (how many times the condition is true)

Comment: then it would help to know something about what your criteria is.  If you can encode it as a generator function, you could use that in your for loop, and skip the `if makeadir()` completely.

Comment: @ufdul how about the edit?

Comment: I am trying to check if an image label is not too close to the edge of the image. If this condition is true then I will create a folder and save this image to the folder.

Comment: so what? you have a list of images?  take my first example, and change the for loop to be `for i, image in enumerate(imagelist):`  and have `makeadir(image)` be the criteria.  does that do it for you?  You should really add this info into the question.  the question leaves us guessing a lot here.

Answer (score 4):

```
import os

condition_success = 0 # set initial 0 
while True:
    condition_success += 1 # get counter for condition to increment if condition is true:
    # By default this will create folder within same directory
    os.makedirs("folder"+str(condition_success)) # creates folder1 if condition_success is 1
```

> to create directory somewhere else set path to it
>
> ```
> path = "/path/"
> os.makedirs(path + "folder"+str(condition_success))
> ```
>
> or you can directly create it as
>
> ```
>   os.makedirs("/path/folder"+str(condition_success))
> ```

## alternate way:

> if you want that condition within sub condition you can use if
>   statement to execute it or to break your condition to prevent infinite
>   loop
>
> ```
> condition_success = 0
> usr_input = int(input("Enter number to create number of folder/execute condition: ")) # get number from user input
> while True:
>   condition_success += 1 # get counter for condition to increment if condition is true:
>   # By default this will create folder within same directory
>   os.makedirs("folder"+str(condition_success)) # creates folder1 if condition_success is 1
>   if condition_success >= usr_input:
>       break
> ```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be by using the while loop and using a counter to count how many times it gets looped.

```
import os

counter=1
while statement:
    os.mkdir('folder{}'.format(str(counter)))
    counter += 1
    # give a new value to your statement to keep creating or stop creating directories
    statement = true
```